# how to get array object to get values

Tags: arrays, mongodb

Following document:

```
{ itemid : 101, vegitable : { nuts : [ { nutsid : 'n101', nutname : 'almonds', price :100 }, { nutid : 'f102', nutname : 'kishmish', price :150}],
                              fruits : [{ frid : 'n101', fname : 'apple',price : 100} }]  }
},{
itemid : 102, vegitable : { nuts : [ { nutsid : 'n101', nutname : 'kashu', price :100 }, { nutid : 'f102', nutname : 'draksh', price :150}],
                              fruits : [{ frid : 'n101', fname : 'mango',price : 100} }]  }
}
```

I want the following output exact 100 /- `price` `fruitname` and `nutname` in array

```
items = [ 'almonds','apple', 'kashu','mongo']
```

Comment: have a look on [mongo's `aggregation`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/aggregation/) gonna solve this for you (by yourself).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- `$filter` to iterate loop of array `nuts` or `fruits`, and get filtered documents that equal to `price 100`,
- `$map` to iterate loop of above filtered documents and get only name field
- `$concatArarays` to concat both array `nuts` and `fruits`
- `$unwind` deconstruct `vegitable` array that we have created in above stage
- `$group` by null and construct array of `vegitable`

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $addFields: {
      vegitable: {
        $concatArrays: [
          {
            $map: {
              input: {
                $filter: {
                  input: "$vegitable.nuts",
                  cond: { $eq: ["$$this.price", 100] }
                }
              },
              in: "$$this.nutname"
            }
          },
          {
            $map: {
              input: {
                $filter: {
                  input: "$vegitable.fruits",
                  cond: { $eq: ["$$this.price", 100] }
                }
              },
              in: "$$this.fname"
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  { $unwind: "$vegitable" },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: null,
      items: { $push: "$vegitable" }
    }
  }
])
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/RuJOogj9-c5)